# Can't open Windows Phone project in Windows 8.1+ Universal App using Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

Trying to open a Universal App for Windows 8.1+ in the Visual Studio 2015 RC and everything aside from the Windows Phone project opens fine.

Error Message:

> "The application which this project type is based on was not found." 
>   
> Link given by message - [Visual Studio 2013
>   Compatibility](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39)

The project file says VS 12 so I'm pretty sure I created it in VS 2013.
Is there any way to open the project without recreating the entire solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grabbed the VS 2015 RC ISO and started up the install.  I guess about 80% of the features hadn't been checked the last time I installed VS 2015.  Selected all and installed.  Problem solved.

Edit: Mason reminded me below that you can use Programs and Features in control panel to change or repair the installation without the need for the ISO. I'd recommend this over obtaining a fresh copy of the installer image.

Comment: I don't think you needed to grab the installer again. Simply go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, Visual Studio 2015 RC, Right Click, Modify, check the features you need.

Comment: Ah, that's right, I forgot about that.
For anybody with the same problem, follow mason's solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should find if you checked the option of windows 8.1 and windows 
phone 8.1 Tools.(like the picture) 
vs2015 rc is somewhat different from vs2013. 
mason`s approach is right.
and the last thing ensure that you computer system is windows10
I don`t know if vs2015 can run errorless in other system

Comment: It works on 8.1.  Installed all the missing features and everything is working great now.