# Visual Studio 2015 - Can't Open MVC4 Projects

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

for some reason, this:

[image: Incompatible MVC Project]

And according to the migration report: `The application which this project type is based on was not found.`

When I try to open any MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2015 (well, the three I've got lying around) VS tells me these projects are incompatible. All other projects that I've tried have worked just fine.

My workmates have installed the same version of Visual Studio and are able to open these projects just fine. I've installed the exact same options as the folks who can open the MVC4 projects but to no avail.

Not sure what to try next?

Obviously this is not killing me, but I'd rather use VS2015 for everything - and if I get these projects working I can happily uninstall VS2013, saving me valuable SSD space.

Any help figuring out why I'm an idiot/VS2015 is protecting its brother (VS2013) would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Suggestion: it's worth double-checking the options.  Specifically, try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260929/cant-open-windows-phone-project-in-windows-8-1-universal-app-using-visual-stud: Simply go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, Visual Studio 2015 RC, Right Click, Modify, check the features you need.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4, but that's what I did already (although I've got VS 2015 installed, not the RC).

Comment: Q: Out of curiousity, have you tried creating a new MVC project in MSVS 2015?  Does that work?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, @paulsm4, but I was under the impression that one could not create new MVC-4 projects in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Note for others, I upgraded the projects to MVC5, it was relatively painless. I would still like to know why I can't open MVC-4 projects though :).

Comment: I would, too.  One final suggestion: consider *deleting* both MSVS 2013 and MSVS 2015, rebooting, making sure everything is "clean" (perhaps rebooting yet again).  Then install MSVS 2015.  Pay careful attention to the "features", and make sure *everything* that might be *remotely* related to MVC4 is checked "Yes".  Let us know what happens!

Comment: Q: Any luck?  Get it working?

Comment: @paulsm4: I have not, but I've been too busy to spend more time on it :).

Comment: well I can open those, build them run them - all no problem - but as always Intelisense in razor views is broken in VS2015 so it's useless

Answer (score 3):

MVC4 won't shipped with VS2015 by default. You need to install it. Find it here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Comment: I had problems with System.Net.Http dll in old project targeting 4.0 using Visual studio 2015. This trick worked for me! thanks!